# Raphaeljs: Why is paper.getFont() undefined? Cufon.replace() works

Tags: javascript, fonts, raphael

I'm using Raphaeljs and I'm trying to get paper.print() to work in a .js-file. I've Cufonized a font and imported the .font.js file into the html-file. In the html-file, Cufon.replace('h1') works (since text with this tag in the body use the font) but I can't get paper.print() to work in my .js file.

According to the .font.js-file the font family is "Champagne & Limousines", so I'm trying to get the font by calling

```
paper.getFont('Champagne & Limousines')
```

An alert shows that the result of the getFont-call is undefined. I try to print letters by doing the following:

```
var letters = paper.print(100, 100, "STRINGSTRING", paper.getFont('Champagne & Limousines'), 40);
```

This does nothing. I've done some other things in the javascript file, so I know there's nothing wrong with paper, nor with including the javascript file in the html file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be the ampersand? If you rename the font to Champagne does that work? If so perhaps you need to write & as &amp; in the getFont call.

Comment: I changed the "font-family" attribute to "Champagne" (for one of the different kinds of fonts) in the .font.js file, but
alert(paper.getFont('Champagne')); 
unfortunately still returns "undefined" and the print still doesn't work. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download the latest version of Raphael.That solved this for me.